# Prevent hover effect from looping

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a hover effect which toggles a top block to `slide up/down` at the same time the `bottom block slides up / down`.

As you can see in the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wmaL1pm5/1/

However, if you swipe your mouse fast on and off the block the hover effects keeps repeating even if you are not on that block anymore.

In my HTML I have 2 row's with each 3 row containing 3 of these blocks. If you swipe your mouse of these rows all of the blocks are repeating their hover effect.

How can I prevent the hover effect from looping if you hover another block or if your mouse is on the current block.

Below my current jQuery code:

```
$(".usp-hover").mouseenter( function(){
     $( this ).find( ".usp-block-title" ).slideToggle('slow')
     $( this ).find( ".usp-block-hover" ).removeClass("usp-block-hidden");
     $( this ).find( ".usp-block-hover" ).slideDown('slow')
});

$(".usp-hover").mouseleave( function(){
     $( this ).find( ".usp-block-title" ).slideToggle('slow')
     $( this ).find( ".usp-block-hover" ).slideToggle('slow')
});
```

Comment: In the fiddle @chsdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***you must Stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements.***

```
$(".usp-hover").mouseleave( function(){
    $( this ).find( ".usp-block-title" ).stop( true, true ).slideToggle('slow')
    $( this ).find( ".usp-block-hover" ).stop( true, true ).slideToggle('slow')
});
```

Comment: The true,true fixed it for the mouse leave! Thanks for helping guys.

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the previous animation by using the `.stop()` method:

```
$(".usp-hover").mouseenter( function(){
    $( this ).find( ".usp-block-title" ).stop().slideToggle('slow')
    $( this ).find( ".usp-block-hover" ).removeClass("usp-block-hidden");
    $( this ).find( ".usp-block-hover" ).stop().slideDown('slow')
});

$(".usp-hover").mouseleave( function(){
    $( this ).find( ".usp-block-title" ).stop().slideToggle('slow')
    $( this ).find( ".usp-block-hover" ).stop().slideToggle('slow')
});
```

This will stop queuing up your animations and only display the latest and thus prevent the loop.

Comment: Works quite well if you keep it slow, but if you swipe your mouse over a couple of these blocks some of the hover toggles are not returned.